# VueJS/Laravel - Sharing props between Laravel and Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have defined a component called `EditorNavigation.vue` like so:

```
<template>
   <div>
   <ul>
      <li v-bind:class="{'is-active':(active === field.id)}" v-for="field in fields">
          <a :href="'/streams/' + stream_token + '/fields/' + field.id">{{field.name}}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["fields", "active", "stream_token"],
        created() {
            this.fields = JSON.parse(this.fields);
            this.active = JSON.parse(this.active);
            this.stream_token = JSON.parse(this.stream_token);
        }
    };

</script>
```

As you can see in my component, I need three variables:

1. Fields (array of all fields)
2. An unique token for a specific resource
3. The current active field id (so I can set the `is-active` class).

In my Laravel view file, I use the component like this:

`show.blade.php`

```
<editor-navigation fields="{{ json_encode($stream->fields) }}" active="{{ json_encode($field->id) }}" stream_token="{{ json_encode($field->stream->token) }}"></editor-navigation>
```

So above code works fine, however it feels a bit "messy" - since I need to use the `editor-navigation` component in a lot of pages, and I am wondering what will happen as soon as I need another variable sent to it - I have to update it in all places.

Comment: Why not just pass one object as a prop with all your data in it?  `props: ['data']` then do `JSON.parse(this.data.fields)` etc.

Comment: Are you always going to be passing the same data to `EditorNavigation` or will you be passing different data depending on where it is in your app?

Comment: It will always be the same, just from different blade views..

Comment: You could look into using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/). It's a centralized place in the frontend to store data and to retireve data from. You could see it as a database for the frontend.